# Silverlight: ContentPresenter inside ComboBox.ItemTemplate crashes everything when clicked on the ComboBox

Tags: silverlight, combobox, crash, itemtemplate, contentpresenter

I'm trying to render a Canvas as the Content of the ContentPresenter below. I load the canvas dynamically from a file and bind the control to the content. Everything works well and it gets displayed but if you click the ComboBox it crashes Silverlight and the Browser (any of them). Anybody got an idea what im doing (horribly) wrong?

```
..
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Grid>                           
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SomeElement}"/>
    </Grid>          
  </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
..
```

Comment: There is insufficient information to diagnose the problem. *The XAML you provided works fine.* Can you provide more code/Xaml including the binding and data loading?

Comment: Please be more specific about how you experience the crash. Chances are that an exception is thrown but what exception is it?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you bind the canvas? You should make sure you do it in an override to [`OnApplyTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms588593%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) in your [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609785%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) after `base.OnApplyTemplate` has been called; otherwise, you can't guarantee that the `ComboBox` template has been applied yet.